# How to get results from K Nearest Neighbour Regression

Tags: canvas, data-mining, orange

I want to know the best optimasation for 5 attributes who determine a regressoinal numerical class. The K Nearest Neighbour Regression is the best regression method, but how can i get solid results(as in numerical results for the best values for the attributes) based on this regression method?

Comment: Your question may be a better fit for Stackoverflow's sister site: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this depending upon what type of software you use.  You might want to determine first if indeed K-NN regression is the best algorithm for your needs, assuming you're not overfitting, etc.  Some type of Principal Component Analysis (PCA) or other analysis might be in order first to give a sense of attribute priority.

In Weka, you can do this by embedding (wrapping) the LinearNNSearch method inside an IBk learner.  In effect, you allow the algorithm to optimize the number of neighbors by means of a repeated, hold-one-out cross-validation process. Instructions on how to do this is located:

http://infochim.u-strasbg.fr/CS3/program/Tutorials/Tutorial2a.pdf